# Masking an image with all elements with a class

Tags: css, mask

I have an image gradient that covers the entire body and I have a grid of more images (there are 4 in each row). I want all of the images in the grid to have the gradient overlay, but hide the rest of the gradient.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: black;
}

.image-grid {
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
}

.image-gradient {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 60%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.image-container {
    margin: 14px 14px;
    width: 444px;
    height: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.image {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bucket List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <img class="image-gradient" src="images/gradient.jpg"></img>
    <section class="image-grid">
        <div class="image-row">
            <div class="image-container">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="image" id="igloo" src="images/igloo.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="image-container">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="image" id="interstellar" src="images/interstellar.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="image-container">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="image" id="gamedev" src="images/gamedev.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="image-container">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="image" id="icehockey" src="images/icehockey.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="image-row">
            <div class="image-container">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="image" id="zipline" src="images/zipline.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried using mask-image and setting it to element(class) but nothing changed. I also tried clip-path and setting it to element(class) but nothing changed again. I am out of ideas and do not know how to implement this.

Comment: You should also add a bit of HTML, and put it all into a snippet to help people helping you !

Comment: Good thinkin @Dolotboy